# Visual Studio 2010 runs installer when I debug

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010

I've been using a solution since VS2010 was released. My solution has a number of projects in it. Until a couple of weeks ago, all was fine. All of a sudden, whenever I click the button to start debugging my code, the Visual Studio 2010 installer starts.

It takes around 5 minutes for it to complete and then I am able to debug as normal. If I restart the debug session then I have to wait for the installer again.

I haven't tried cancelling the installer, but I just want to stop it altogether.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue? How can I solve this? Its doing my head in!! :S

Thanks
Neil

Comment: Never heard of this before. I guess you've already tried a full repair and it's still happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend reinstalling Visual Studio. If that doesn't help something else might be wrong with your system and you may end up to re-image it. Being able to re-image a development PC can be a life-saver at times.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "Visual Studio 2010 installer" do you mean the installer for Visual Studio 2010 or an installer project inside your solution?  If it's the latter then you may want to check that that project isn't specified as the startup project (right'click Solution -> Properties -> Common Properties -> Startup Project -> Choose "Single startup project" and specify the project you want the debugger to run when you press F5 or the debugger button.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I meant the actual installer for VS2010.. I never solved it, but work provided me with a new computer, so with a fresh install, it stopped happening. Guess it was something on that PC....